# Send Email Per Each Rep Sales On Saved Search

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I am doing some practices in Netsuite, in which I have a saved search to see the tasks of each sales representative, I created the email sending to my email, this as a test run.

Now I would like that information to be received by the sales representative, which is why I ask the question.

Can I create a saved search and based on the sales representative send his information without seeing the others? Or it should be a search for each representative.

I appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - this is what the Recipients From Results subtab is for.  Select Sales Rep under Recipient Field in this subtab, and set up the rest of the options under the Email tab as you would if sending to specific recipients.  The search results with values that match the selected field will be sent to the respective entity.

For example, if the results are as per the table below, Joe would get an email with three rows and Bill would get the other two:

| Sales Rep | Order | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 123 | 112.33 |
| Joe | 125 | 22.11 |
| Joe | 235 | 5684.99 |
| Bill | 356 | 564.99 |
| Bill | 124 | 2365.87 |

Note that you should select the Summarize Scheduled Emails option, otherwise Joe would receive three emails instead of one email with three results and so on.